# import R (ramda) into typescript .ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I am attempting to use **Ramda.js** as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/ramda/index.d.ts" />
module App {
    var settab = R.once((element) => current(element));  
    function current(li: any) {
        // ...
    }    
}
```

> I get error, **Cannot find name 'R'**

In the case of the `ramda/index.d.ts` file, the declaration (with detail omitted) is as follows:

```
declare var R: R.Static;    
declare namespace R {
    type Ord = number | string | boolean;
    interface Static {
        // .........
    }
}

export = R;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to import it using the `import` statement:

```
import * as R from "ramda";
```

Also, you don't have to use `/// <reference />` anymore, just do `npm install --save @types/ramda`.

Comment: I get the error 'cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'. Which module option will get me closest to what I used to have with `/// <reference />`?

Comment: You can set `compilerOptions.module` as `commonjs` in your `tsconfig.json` and use `import`statements.