# Does the entire file get loaded into memory using import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I have a question about the import statement that is defined in ES6. Using ES6 import function, you can define the given an object  which has been exported from the module either implicitly (because the entire module is exported) or explicitly (using the export statement). I was wondering if there was a memory benefit to using the explicit export. Will it only load those modules into memory or will it load the entire module into memory, and just give you access to the defined modules?

```
import {foo, bar} from '/modules/my-module.js';
foo();
bar();
// vs
import module from '/modules/my-module.js';
module.foo();
module.bar();
// This can apply to require as well
const {foo, bar} = require('/modules/my-module.js');
foo();
bar();
// vs
const module = require('/modules/my-module.js');
module.foo();
module.bar();
```

Comment: FYI - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I can't answer this question with 100% certainty, but I think your wording is maybe a little imprecise.  I would guess that what's critical is what is _imported_ not what is _exported_.  Minimizing the scope of the _import_ by picking specific functions or attributes from the exported interface probably uses less memory.

Comment: Note that `import` and `require()` are **very** different things. Suggest asking about one or the other.

Comment: What implementation are you referring to? It may be different for native, polyfilled and bundled modules. Was es6-module-loader tag chosen randomly?

Comment: Also note that `import module from "path";` imports the *default export*, if any, not the whole module. If you want the whole module, you'd use `import * as module from "path";`.

Comment: Will come back later with a proper answer (have to disappear), but for ES2015 modules, the full module is loaded per spec. But if an implementation does "tree shaking", parts of that module could be GC'd fairly quickly if they haven't been imported. So there's benefit, potentially, to only importing what you need.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My apologizes. I refer to ES6 native, though knowing the answer for bundled modules as well would be good to know, but this question is mainly for ES6 native..

Comment: To add to TJ's most previous comment (yes, the entire file is loaded by the browser), this can be seen in Paul Irish's demo ToDo app that implements modules natively. Go to the site, look at the helpers.js file in the resource list. You will see the entire file. Then look at what he imports in the bootstrap.js file ($on):  https://paulirish.github.io/es-modules-todomvc/

Answer (score 3):

Answering for ES2015 modules (`import` and `export`, not `require()`):

**TL;DR** - The whole module is loaded per spec, but an implementation (or bundler, if you use one) may be able to optimize when it can reliably determine that it can do so without violating the spec. (Whether it does so is another question.) Amongst other things, that means your code would need to avoid `eval` or `new Function` in code that can touch the imported module binding, and not use dynamic property access on it. (E.g., `mod.foo` would be fine, but `mod[name]` where `name` is determined at runtime would not.) Personally, I lean toward importing what I need.

**A bit more detail:**

Let's say we have `module1.js`:

```
import { a } from "./module2.js";

function main() {
    a();
}

main();
```

...and `module2.js`:

```
export function a() {
    console.log("a called");
}
export function b() {
    return c() * 2;
}
function c() {
    return 42;
}
```

If `module1` is the starting point, it goes roughly like this:

- `module1.js`'s source text is parsed and its imports and exports are identified and used to fill in (conceptual) objects representing its live bindings for imports and exports; the values of those bindings are not initialized yet.
- Since it imports from `module2`, the same thing is done for `module2.js`.
- Since that's the full graph, a depth-first evaluation process starts evaluating modules. Our deepest module is `module2`, so `module2.js`'s source text is evaluated (run), initializing its export bindings (and the other private things it creates and fills in).
- Then, all its dependencies satisfied, the same is done for `module1.js`.

(It gets complicated for cyclic-dependencies, let's leave those aside.)

Remember that bindings are live, so if (for instance) `module2` changed the value of `a`, that change would be reflected in the binding that `module1` is using.

So at this point, both modules have been fully loaded and initialized, and that's where the spec leaves off.

Subject to adhering to the specification, implementations can do *tree-shaking*: Identifying things they can prune once the full tree is established, or even things they can avoid creating in the first place (though with JavaScript, static analysis can only take you so far; but avoiding `eval`, `new Function`, dynamic property access, and such helps). So in theory, a sufficiently-optimized engine could get rid of `module2`'s `b` and `c` since they aren't used by anything (`a` doesn't reference them and doesn't use `eval` or `new Function`, and `module1` only uses `a`), or perhaps even avoid creating them at all.

Some bundlers also do tree-shaking, trying to determine what parts of a module aren't used anywhere and leaving those bits out of the bundled file.

Now suppose you imported "the whole module":

```
import * as mod2 from "./module2.js";

function main() {
    mod2.a();
}

main();
```

I haven't gotten down-and-dirty with the details of JavaScript tree-shaking, but my sense is you've made life more difficult for a bundler or JavaScript engine to do tree-shaking, because `mod2` has a property referencing `b` and it has to prove that you never use it.

Note that if you really want the prefix, you can always rename on import:

```
import { a as mod2_a } from "./module2.js";
```

...though granted it's a lot more verbose.

There's been some talk on [es-discuss](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss) about adding further syntax to `import` to simplify that (though not a lot so far, I think the focus in this area is on [`import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) and [`import.meta`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) for now), so perhaps eventually you'll be able to do something where you list the things you want and a pseudo-object to put them on.

Comment: Using the namespace is fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746950/785065

Comment: @loganfsmyth: It would be nice to have something backing up Bergi's answer there, which lacks citations. Given who you are, do you have your own experience of implementing tree-shaking to suggest that `import * as` doesn't make it more difficult? (Provided you don't use dynamic property access or similar on the object, since that would make it impossible.)

Comment: Fair point. I unfortunately haven't spent any time looking at existing implementation logic itself, just done enough to know the user-facing behavior. I don't know specifically how Webpack and Rollup decide what is used and how well they handle escape analysis and such for the import object.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Okay, thanks -- was kind of hoping you'd had to get into that area. :-)