# How can I use namespace import without importing everything?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module

We use lodash in an angular app written with typescript.  Currently we import lodash as follows:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

//.. code which uses _.pluck()
```

However, for the sake of tree shaking, we want to change to the following:

```
import {pluck, delay} from 'lodash';

//.. code which uses _.pluck() needs changed to pluck()
```

The problem is we need to do a lot of tedious code changes because using the second import method loses the namespace of `_` and there could be name conflicts.  Is there a way of specifying the things we want to import but maintain the namespace?  I was thinking something as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
import {pluck, delay} as _ from 'lodash';

//.. code which uses _.pluck() needs changed to pluck()
```

Comment: Tree shaking works just fine with `import * as _ from 'lodash';`, [there is no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746950/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in import but you can create the `_` object manually.

```
import { pluck, delay } from 'lodash';

const _ = { pluck, delay };
```