# Webpack - How does export method effect Tree Shaking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

For utility functions and consts I usually use named exports.

```js
//utilities.js
export function someFunction(param){...}
export function someFunction2(param){...}


//someModule.js
import {someFunction} from "./utilities.js"
```

But sometimes, I export them as the default object.

```js
//styleUtilities.js
export function someFunction(param){...}
export function someFunction2(param){...}
export default {someFunction, someFunction2}

//someModule.js
import styleUtilities from "./styleUtilities" 

const {someFunction} = styleUtilities
```

When exporting as default object, does it disrupt tree shaking for unused values in Webpack?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "*when there is a strong connection between the tools*". The connection ([cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))) between them is why they are placed in the same module in the first place? What's the point of putting them in an object?

Comment: "*When exporting as object, does it disrupt tree shaking for unused values in Webpack?*" - Yes. If all you want is having a `styleUtilities` name in the importing module, use named exports and `import * as styleUtilities from "./styleUtilities"`.

Comment: @Bergi, It provides order. Naming can use different conventions. When I'm looking for a certain tool, I usually don't remember it's exact name. It could be convenient to remember that all style utilities are under `styleUtilities`, and then just type `styleUtilities` and enjoy autocomplete for available values.

Answer (score 3):

> When exporting as default object, does it disrupt tree shaking for unused values in Webpack?

Yes.

> It could be convenient to remember that all style utilities are under `styleUtilities`.

For that, you should still be using named exports in your `utilities.js` module. Then when importing that module in `someModule.js`, use namespace import syntax:

```
import * as styleUtilities from "./utilities.js";

styleUtilities.someFunction();
```

This will [still allow tree-shaking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45735534/1048572), and offer the choice of import style to the consumer of your module (not forcing an object upon them).

Comment: Thanks, but editor's autocomplete won't recognize `styleUtilities`

Comment: That sounds like a bug in your editor's autocomplete, then. What are you using? Does it not provide autocomplete on `import` statements either, or auto-import of undeclared variables?

Comment: I'm talking about autoComplete on the fly. Using named import in any js/ts module I can type `some` which will suggest `someFunction` and `someFunction2`. In the second method I can typen `styleU` and it will suggest `styleUtilities`. What do you mean by autoComplete on import statements?

Comment: Oh, I thought of real autocomplete that inspects types and knows what properties an object has, not just using similar identifiers in the same file. Such an autocomplete could also expand `import { someF… } from 'utilities';`.